# How to load child HTML page content from source HTML page without scrolling to bottom of the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I am using jQuery to load a child HTML page. The child HTML page has a list of div's and the numbers can vary up to 50 div's. I am using *Jquery.get* to load the child HTML in parent. I have a requirement to view the content of the child containing all div's without scrolling to the bottom of the page. I tried to use the below code, but the div's from the child keep repeating after all the div's are displayed. How can I achieve this?

**Parent.html**

```
<div id="parent"></div>

<script>
    $.get('child.html', function(data){ // Loads content into the 'data' variable.
        $('#parent').append(data); // Injects 'data' after the #div element.
    });

    $(document).scroll(function(e){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.7){

            $.get('child.html', function(data){ // Loads content into the 'data' variable.
                $('#parent').append(data); // Injects 'data' after the #div element.
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

**Child.html**

```
<div class='row list' id=1>
    <span>1</span>
</div>

<div class='row list' id=2>
    <span>2</span>
</div>

<div class='row list' id=3>
    <span>3</span>
</div>

<div class='row list' id=4>
    <span>4</span>
</div>

<div class='row list' id=5>
    <span>5</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Consider using `.load()` instead: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Hi, tried .load() but no luck. The scrollbar behaves normally and I am able to scroll down till the bottom of the page to see all div's . i need to load all the div's by scrolling but prevent scroll down to bottom and i do not want to div's to be repeating again.

Comment: The issue is still a little unclear. You refer to "*requirement to view the content of the child containing all div's without scrolling to bottom of the page*." This is unclear and does not make sense. Uou also say, "*div's from the child keep repeating after all the div's are displayed*," and that's not clear either. Is this going to be some type of infinite scroll action?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. Yes it is like an infinite scrolling. I have attached an image in the question for reference. Please have a look. You can see that the div's are repeating again once it reaches number 30 which i do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to load 50 *DIV* elements from the `child.html` file at a time. To do this, we need to track how many items have been loaded and then filter the HTML before loading / appending it to the document.

We want to create a flow / state diagram to understand what is needed.

1. Initial Load

- Populate `parent` element with first 50 items from *child.html*

2. User reads content, scrolls down page
3. User reaches 70% of document height

- Request next 50 elements
- Append next result set to `parent`

**Note:** It would be preferable to use a **Server Side Script**, like PHP, that can serve up the data in chunks.

As I understand it currently, `child.html` is static and contains N number of elements. JavaScript/jQuery has no way to load a specific number of items. The entire document will be loaded each time. Using `.load()`, we can filter for a specific selector.

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the URL parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

I thought we could use `:lt()`, like so:

$("#parent").load("child.html .row:lt(50)");

This is deprecated:

> As of jQuery 3.4, the `:lt` pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using `.slice()`. For example, `:lt(3)` can be replaced with a call to `.slice( 0, 3 )`.

Do this, we would then revert back to `$.get()` like so.

```
$.get("child.html", function(ht){
  $("#parent").append($(ht).find(".row").slice(0,50));
});
```

This will work yet is not optimal as the [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request will return the entire document each time. If this is the case, it would be best to load the entire document initially and then reveal more items as the User scrolls down. This defeats the purpose.

If you want to try it, here is an example:

```
$(function() {
  var count = 0;

  function getNextSet(url, n) {
    var ht;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      var start = count;
      count = count + n;
      ht = $(data).find(".row").slice(start, count);
    });
    return ht;
  }

  $("#parent").append(getNextSet("child.html", 50));

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(this).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.7) {
      $("#parent").append(getNextSet("child.html", 50));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your valuable time to share the solution. it helped me